# Regex to match ONLY 2-digit numbers in a string

Tags: regex, go

I need to read a string with digits and letters by input and see if there are strings with only 2 successive digits and then display them.

For example, if the string is

```
123j3d7djabsd87hbdsak27dbjsak374jdscu2kd389jd34
```

there are 3 substrings that match

```
87, 27 and 34
```

I can partially solve it with
`\d{2}` but it will also took substrings with more than 2 digits.

I'm also working with golang and it doesn't support lookahead so i dn't thik this will work `(?<!\d)\d\d(?!\d)`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    expression := `\d\d`

    verExp := regexp.MustCompile(expression)

    text := "36a45yk342ml29"

    matches := verExp.FindAllString(text, -1)
    for _, match := range matches {
        fmt.Println("Find:", match)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you match all digit sequences with `\d{2,}` and then filter out those you don't need later?

Comment: @InSync Yeah, that's the way I tried to approach it but I thought that maybe there was a better way to solve it.

Comment: `(\D|^)(\d\d)(\D|$)`. Double digits are in capture group 2.

Answer (score 0):

Go language uses [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) regex and that does support regex lookarounds (which would makes this trivial in Perl or other PCRE languages).

You best bet might be to *capture* the two digit sequences like so:

```
\d{3,}|(\d\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QJnw1Z/1)

You then ignore the match of longer sequences and only use the capture groups.

Since the LH side of the `|` alteration has higher precedence that the RH side, all longer runs of 3 or more digits will be matched there. Exactly two digits match on the RH side, and a single digit is not matched.

It is a variant of [this](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) regex trick.

---

As stated in comments, with your example, you could potentially do:

```
(?:[^\d]|^)(\d{2})(?:[^\d]|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJTCK8/1)

However, this regex does not work with sequences separated by a single letter. With a single nondigit between two matches, the negated character classes overlap so the second match fails.

The first regex DOES work in that case since the `(\d\d)` matches all separate sequences of two digits.

Comment: Match 1 is `123`, so your regex does not do the thing the OP requested.

Comment: As stated: It *captures* the two digit sequences and sacrificially matches longer sequences. The first alternate matches the longer sequences. It is a variant of [this regex trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick)

Comment: Wouldn't `(?:[^\d]|^)(\d{2})(?:[^\d]|$)` work and just reading the capture group (and ignoring the non-capture-groups)?  [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/xJTCK8/1)

Comment: That does work indeed. Added to the answer...

Comment: @h2ooooooo @dawg That won't work if two 2-digit sequences are separated by only one non-digit (e.g. `12f34`).

Comment: @InSync: Good catch! `\d{3,}|(\d\d)` *does* work in that case however.